# How to get a number of monospace letters that fit in a line of given width?

Tags: html, css, xslt

I need to implement a pixel-perfect markup. The idea is the following: there are two strings that need to be printed as a single block of text. The text has to be split into lines. The first string has to be formatted in one way, the second one in another. Here's a sample of what might be there:

[image: markup example]

I think I might use a `<table>` for each line and place `<p>aragraphs` in it to get different font styles. My problem is that the only things I might use for that are XSL and HTML+CSS. So I wish to write a template that will provide the required HTML as its output.

For that I need to know how many letters can be placed in a single line (line width and font size can can change) and to implement line breaks on words where necessary. I will use a monospace font. Is there a way to calculate the number of letters that will fit in a line, depending on line width an font size?

Comment: Why can’t you just use `<p>` markup and set a width on the element, with suitable `text-indent` value and with the first text wrapped in a `span` element so that it can be styled?

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. But the main problem still remains. I need to split the text into a number of `<p>` to make each line underlined. And the first line may be of different length and the font-size may vary.

Comment: So the point is that the underlining (or bottom border?) should extend past the text, spanning the entire available width? So it would be underlining of lines, rather than of text?